# Markdown for music notation fragments

Tags: notation

is there an equivalent of JSFiddle or Markdown for music notation?  That would be useful for posting fragments of notation into StackExchange questions, as well as other blogs/wikis/webpages.  math.stackexchange.com does something similar with MathJax for equations.

Comment: If you are asking about it *for this site* then this is a meta question (and discussed most recently here http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/poll-do-we-prefer-abc-or-lilypond-for-site-markdown ); This would be a good question for the main site if you're asking in general about approaches to enable music markup in websites, but, to me, it's not clear from the wording of this question that that is what you are asking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ABCjs is a Javascript library implementing ABC notation. The [source code](https://github.com/paulrosen/abcjs) and [documentation](https://paulrosen.github.io/abcjs/) are available on GitHub.

You can find a great deal of information on ABC notation itself on the [ABC homepage](http://abcnotation.com/), in particular, the [ABC standard](http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1).

SE Music Practice and Theory [supports ABCjs](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/documentation-for-abcjs).

```
X:1
T:Spiffy Example
K:none
M:4/4
L:1/4
c/4 | c4 |]
w:ta | da! |]
```

Additionally, you can use an [external editor](https://editor.drawthedots.com/), with a newer version of the library, to write things out.

Comment: For those using vscode, there is now an extension available, by yours truly -> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alensiljak.abcjs-vscode

Answer (score 2):

[My VexFlow](http://my.vexflow.com/) is the closest thing I can think of to being "JSFiddle for music notation". You need to create an account before using the site, but it's free and lets you create notation snippets that are then hosted on the site and can be viewed by anyone you give the link to.

In general, it's more geared toward writing articles with notation examples embedded (it supports Markdown syntax for text), but it works just fine for standalone music snippets too. It uses [VexTab](http://www.vexflow.com/vextab/tutorial.html) as the format for entering music, which can display both Western notation and guitar tablature.

I've put together a simple example named [What's the name of this tune?](http://my.vexflow.com/articles/348) to demonstrate what the end result might look like.

Comment: The links appear to be broken.

Comment: My understanding is that Vex is writing the actual notes in JavaScript? ABC would be more like Markdown, in comparison.

Comment: @AlenSiljak The equivalent of ABC or Markdown here would be VexTab, as a human-friendly input format. The rendering engine VexFlow can consume VexTab so it's not necessary to write any Javascript (unless you want to or need to, for advanced usage).